# Getting 3D coordinates of a 3d object using Java3D

Tags: java, java-3d

I need your help. I'm new with Java3D. What I need to do is get the coordinates (x,y,z) for each point in a Java3D object without using a mouse click or any input from the user.

So far, I've been successful in putting the 3D object in the universe. But I haven't been able to get geometry points. What I'm planning to do is to get the (x,y,z) from one angle, rotate the object, then get the coordinates again for that angle, repeat this process until 360 degrees rotation.

Any help on how to start on this will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: Here is my code below. Take note that most of it, I only got from few examples I found. Right now, I managed to get the 3d object in the universe.

```
    universe = new VirtualUniverse();
    Locale locale = new Locale(universe);
    sceneBranchGroup = new BranchGroup();

    BranchGroup rootBranch = sceneBranchGroup;
    applicationBounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 100.0);
    Bounds lightBounds = applicationBounds;
    AmbientLight ambLight = new AmbientLight(true, new Color3f(1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f));
    ambLight.setInfluencingBounds(lightBounds);
    rootBranch.addChild(ambLight);

    DirectionalLight headLight = new DirectionalLight();
    headLight.setInfluencingBounds(lightBounds);
    rootBranch.addChild(headLight);

    TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();

    BranchGroup sceneRoot = loadVrmlFile("C:/Users/rache_000/Desktop/wrl files/2b.wrl");
    tg.addChild(sceneRoot);

    rootBranch.addChild(tg);

    ViewPlatform vp = new ViewPlatform();
    vp.setViewAttachPolicy(View.RELATIVE_TO_FIELD_OF_VIEW);
    vp.setActivationRadius(100);

    TransformGroup viewTG = new TransformGroup();
    Transform3D t3d = new Transform3D();
    t3d.setScale(1.0);
    t3d.setTranslation(new Vector3d(0.0, 0.0, -20.0));
    t3d.invert();
    viewTG.setTransform(t3d);

    BranchGroup viewBranchGroup = new BranchGroup();
    Group parentGroup = viewBranchGroup;
    parentGroup.addChild(viewTG);
    parentGroup = viewTG;

    viewTG.addChild(vp);

    View view = new View();

    PhysicalBody physicalBody = new PhysicalBody();
    PhysicalEnvironment physicalEnvirontment = new PhysicalEnvironment();

    view.setPhysicalBody(physicalBody);
    view.setPhysicalEnvironment(physicalEnvirontment);
    view.attachViewPlatform(vp);

    view.setBackClipDistance(100.0);
    view.setFrontClipDistance(1.0);

    GraphicsConfigTemplate3D gc3D = new GraphicsConfigTemplate3D();
    gc3D.setSceneAntialiasing(GraphicsConfigTemplate.PREFERRED);
    GraphicsDevice gd[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getScreenDevices();

    Canvas3D c3d = new Canvas3D(gd[0].getBestConfiguration(gc3D));
    c3d.setSize(300, 300);
    view.addCanvas3D(c3d);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(c3d, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    doLayout();

    pickCanvas = new PickCanvas(c3d, sceneBranchGroup);
    pickCanvas.setMode(PickTool.GEOMETRY_INTERSECT_INFO);
    pickCanvas.setTolerance(4.0f);

    Background back = new Background(new Color3f(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f));

    back.setApplicationBounds(applicationBounds);
    rootBranch.addChild(back);

    locale.addBranchGraph(rootBranch);

    locale.addBranchGraph(viewBranchGroup);
```

> Currently, this function does not do anything.

```
    getCoordinates(sceneRoot);
```

I know it's just a big chunk of code, but any help will be greatly appreciated. I really have no idea how to approach it and a push in the right direction is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Including some of your current code might be helpful

Comment: Sam cd, you are right. I edited the post and included the code. Thanks.